# Adding Int and signed char value

Tags: c++, c, types, addition

I have the following Code chunk in C - building a win32 binary using VS2012 .

```
int a ;
signed char b[2][4];
UINT c ;
```

c = a + b [1][2];

The actual values happen to be a= 15 ; b [1][2] = -17 ; I believe the value of c should be -2 while the above code gives value of 254

Can someone please help where I am wrong in the above chunk of code.

Thanks very much !!

Comment: Use a debugger. And `UINT` is probably `unsigned`

Comment: hint: UINT UINT UINT UINT UINT

Comment: Does the `U` in `UINT` stand for "unsigned" perchance?

Comment: Welcome to the joys of assigning a negative integer to an unsigned integer variable.

Comment: Yes UINT is typedef of unsigned int

Comment: Surely? `unsigned(-2)` giving 254 would mean that `unsigned int` is 8-bit on your platform.

Comment: It is strange. How do you know/print the value of `c` ?

Comment: Type promotion should result in UINT_MAX - 2 (promote (char) -17 to (int) -17, add 15, then convert (int) -2 to unsigned), not UCHAR_MAX - 2, so if it's actually 254 you're either losing bits when you print the value or you've found a compiler bug.